# Calling a static method using a Type

Tags: c#

How do I call a static method from a `Type`, assuming I know the value of the `Type` variable and the name of the static method?

```
public class FooClass {
    public static FooMethod() {
        //do something
    }
}

public class BarClass {
    public void BarMethod(Type t) {
        FooClass.FooMethod()          //works fine
        if (t is FooClass) {
            t.FooMethod();            //should call FooClass.FooMethod(); compile error
        }
    }
}
```

So, given a `Type t`, the objective is to call `FooMethod()` on the class that is of `Type t`. Basically I need to reverse the `typeof()` operator.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to call [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) method:

```
public class BarClass {
    public void BarMethod(Type t) {
        FooClass.FooMethod(); //works fine
        if (t == typeof(FooClass)) {
            t.GetMethod("FooMethod").Invoke(null, null); // (null, null) means calling static method with no parameters
        }
    }
}
```

Of course in the above example you might as well call `FooClass.FooMethod` as there is no point using reflection for that. The following sample makes more sense:

```
public class BarClass {
    public void BarMethod(Type t, string method) {
        var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(method);
        if (methodInfo != null) {
            methodInfo.Invoke(null, null); // (null, null) means calling static method with no parameters
        }
    }
}

public class Foo1Class {
  static public Foo1Method(){}
}
public class Foo2Class {
  static public Foo2Method(){}
}

//Usage
new BarClass().BarMethod(typeof(Foo1Class), "Foo1Method");
new BarClass().BarMethod(typeof(Foo2Class), "Foo2Method");
```

Comment: Thanks Igor, this will work fine (although I am disappointed in C#--it looks completely un-typesafe)

In my actual code there are many classes that could be in the Type variable, so reflection is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Note, that as 10 years have passed. Personally, I would add extension method:

```
public static TR Method<TR>(this Type t, string method, object obj = null, params object[] parameters) 
    => (TR)t.GetMethod(method)?.Invoke(obj, parameters);
```

and then I could call it with:

```
var result = typeof(Foo1Class).Method<string>(nameof(Foo1Class.Foo1Method));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check into the [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) class and the [GetMethod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt2ztzdc.aspx) methods on Type.

There are a number of different overloads for different situations.