# Static members and interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interface, static

I just went through a handful of SO questions on this topic and found out that this is (currently?) not possible to define static members in interfaces or make static methods virtual. I'm now struggling with a situation. Let me try to depict it with a simple example:

I have an interface named say `IAnimal` with the following definition:

```
interface IAnimal {
    ...
    int Chromosomes {get; } //should ideally be static, but that's not allowed!
    ...
}
```

Then I have a base class Animal that implements `IAnimal` and provides implementation of some methods common to all animals:

```
abstract class Animal : IAnimal { 
    ...
    public abstract int Chromosomes {get; } //necessary becuz of IAnimal
    ...
}
```

Below this I then have `Dog`, `Cat` and `Zebra` classes that inherit from `Animal` and provide concrete implementations of this property for their species.

Now the problem: These classes are discovered at runtime (through `Assembly.LoadFile()` becuz of the pluggable-modules). The discovered classes are kept in a `List<System.Type>` that we later use to create concrete dogs and cats. The input parameter for the creation of an animal is chromosomes number, so for example they'll ask: *Create an animal of the type that has 72 chromosomes.* So I need to somehow get the Chromosome property's value of each `Type` in the `List` and return the first matching `Type`.

Since `Chromosomes` is not static (if it were, I could easily [run a static member of a given Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384976/c-sharp-calling-a-static-method-using-a-type)), am I forced to create a temporary object of each type and then call `Chromosomes` with it, or is there a better way? All the elements in my `List` are guarenteed to be `IAnimal` if that is of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the C# type system isn't geared up for this. It's not *often* a problem, but when it does come up it's a pain :( Some options you might want to think about, all of which start off by removing the existing property:

- Create a separate type hierarchy for the types themselves (`DogType`, `AnimalType` etc) which could also be responsible for creating instances if that's useful. That tends to be a bit of a pain.
- Add an attribute to the type, indicating the number of chromosomes - this only works when the value is constant, of course. You can then find the attribute value with reflection. It won't be enforced at compile-time though.
- Make a static property which can be invoked with reflection, and then add unit tests to ensure that every type which implements the interface *also* has the static property

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Your second suggestion appears to have minimal effect on the existing architecture. The value of Chromosomes is of course constant across the entire species (as is the actual property that I'm working with). Unfortunately `const` can also not be overridden. But the attributes idea is superb. Let me try that.